# status bar disappear when MFMailComposeViewController is loaded

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, statusbar

When the MFMailComposeViewController modal view is loaded, the status bar disappeared.
It doesn't appear again anymore if I navigate back to other view controllers.
So after MFMailComposeViewController is loaded, the apps end up with no status bar.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: after dismissing mail compose view, are you seeing while blank space in place of status bar? If no, then every thing is alright. your app itself might not be having status bar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. my app does have status bar. i enable it in appDelegate [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; I can see the status bar and navigation bar when the app is loaded at first. after i dismiss the mailcompser, the status bar is missing and only navigation bar left. I don't see any blank space for status bar on top.  do i need to enable anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code that launches MFMailComposeViewController, to ensure its not hiding your status bar.

Also on the delrgate for the dismiss you could put:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

Tom.